# VSCode setup for Typescript with Lucid and Deno

Tags: vscode, lucid

Although all my code have been compiling successfully, in VSCode linting for .ts files, I get a warning message for "Could not find name Deno" and "Could not find module '"https://deno.land/x/lucid@0.8.3/mod.ts' or its corresponding type declarations"

I do have the VScode extensions installed for both Deno and typescript, but I'm not sure what else to do. Also, these typescript files are within an Aiken project directory.